# Pandas / Python - Compare numerically each row with all others

Tags: python, pandas

I program in Python and I would like to compare in an optimized way each row of a numerical pandas dataframe with every row of itself.

For example, if I have :

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2], [1,10,1,1,1]])
thr = 0.3
B = A * thr
```

With A as following :

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

With B as following :

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 |
| 3 | 0.3 | 3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |

My aim is to have a dictionary with the rows of B where all cells are inferior to the cells of a given one of A, as following :

```
{
 0:[1,2],
 1:[0,2],
 2:[0,1],
 3:[0,1,2]
}
```

For example, the A's row of index 0 is superior to B's rows of index 1 and 2 ==> So we have "0:[1,2]" in the dictionary.

My question is : what is the best way to compute this, i.e. the fastest in terms of execution time and with the least computational cost please ? Using for loops, pandas function, apply/applymap functions etc... ? Would you have some code in Python to do it ?

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards

Comment: StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service. You should go googling.

Comment: How are you defining superior? sum of rows, all cells compared vs each other? etc.

Comment: @barny Thank you for your helpful feedback. I already tried googling and spent hours to code it, but without reaching good enough performance.

Comment: @HenryEcker I mean all cells compared to each other. For example, strictly A[0,.] = [1,1,1,1,1] > B[0,.]=[0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3] and A[0,.] > B[1,.]=[0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3] because all cells 1 > 0.3. But it's not true for B[3,.] = [0.3, 3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3] since A[0,1] = 1 < B[3,1] = 3. That's why we have the dictionary "0:[1,2]" and not "0:[1,2,3]". Feel free to ask me to reexplain if I didnt explain it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to [`broadcast`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) greater than over both frames and evaluate any rows on axis 2 where [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy-all) values are true:

```
all_greater = (A.values[:, None] > B.values).all(axis=2)
```

```
[[ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True]]
```

Here each column represents a row in B, and each row represents a row from A.
`[True True True False]` indicates index 0 in A is greater than all elements from index 0, 1, 2 in B.

---

From this, create a new frame via [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy-nonzero) + [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy-transpose)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(np.nonzero(all_greater)), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

```
    A  B
0   0  0
1   0  1
2   0  2
3   1  0
4   1  1
5   1  2
6   2  0
7   2  1
8   2  2
9   3  0
10  3  1
11  3  2
12  3  3
```

Then filter out the self matches, [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) into lists:

```
d = df[df['A'].ne(df['B'])].groupby('A')['B'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 1], 3: [0, 1, 2]}
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 10, 1, 1, 1]
])
thr = 0.3
B = A * thr

all_greater = (A.values[:, None] > B.values).all(axis=2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(np.nonzero(all_greater)), columns=['A', 'B'])
d = df[df['A'].ne(df['B'])].groupby('A')['B'].agg(list).to_dict()
print(d)
```